# Is there an apt-get package for Perl's Apache::Log::Parser module?

Tags: 14.04

Is there an apt-get package for Perl's `Apache::Log::Parser` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no package in the Ubuntu repositories and there is no PPA. 
I contend that to the best of my knowledge and belief, so help me Google.

But you can install the CPAN modules via

```
cpan
```

and

```
install Apache::Log::Parser
```

`cpan` is in the package `perl`. But you will have it installed.

Comment: Are you affirming there is, in fact, no package? ...or simply pointing out that I could also install the package via CPAN?

Comment: Updated my answer =)